# How optimize css/less by webpack?

Tags: css, optimization, webpack, less, minify

I have already optimized js, but how optimize css and less files?

I'm not sure what this code do  (it is currently what I have):

```
{
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!less"
},
```

I tried to use:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader
But no result, actually result is error on build.

Maybe is reason what I have one less file and inside a lot of different import.
And I can import css, min.css, less.

```
@import "hud/styling/hud.less";
@import "~video.js/dist/video-js.min.css";
@import "canvas/spots.css";
```

The main goal I should have one js file (as currently I have) with css without comments and spaces generated from less or css.

Comment: Are you talking about `optimization` or `minification` ?

Comment: Actually both. I working on reduce size of my app

Answer (score 0):

There is a packaged called [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin). This is a simple css webpack setup that I use

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

  module: {
    rules: [{
      use: [{
      test: /\.(less|css)$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'less-loader']
        })
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,
      cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
      cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: {removeAll: true } },
      canPrint: true
    }),
  ]

module.exports = config
```

This is just the css webpack part not the complete webpack config

Comment: I can't setup it. node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\lib\helpers.js:15
  return chunk.isInitial() || chunk.parents.length === 0;

Comment: It looks like thats an issue with webpack 3.0.0. [Github Issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/554)

Comment: Try uninstalling extract-text-webpack-plugin and install extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.0-rc.2

Comment: the same TypeError: chunk.isInitial is not a function